# Setting up a trigger in Excel to transpose a column in one sheet to new row in another

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

My query is how to setup a trigger such that if a new column is entered into SheetA, I want it transposed and written into the next available row in SheetB. I did a macro recording and the VBA script is given below:

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
    Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!RC:R[4]C)"
End Sub
```

Kindly advise on how to proceed with this as I am very new to VBA and have no exposure as such to setting up such triggers.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To be clear - when you say a new column is entered, do you mean someone right-clicks and inserts a column, or do you mean that someone adds data to a column? Can you show some starting inputs and expected outputs please to help illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Steph, yeah by new column entry what I suggest is I am using Power QUery plugin in excel which updates each time there is a new addition in the MySQL DB. So it is more like I press refresh and the new entry goes into SheetA. When this happens, I would like a trigger to perform the select and transpose to SheetB. I hope this makes it a bit more clear. i will try posting images.

Answer (score 1):

PowerQuery is [not currently accessable](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7cec158-b691-4174-b3d7-3f6a9f870d9f/power-query-refreshes-on-open-or-via-vba?forum=powerquery) using VBA, however, the refreshing of the query can be controlled using the `Refresh.All` so instead of manually (or doing on open) a refresh of your data and then expecting the trigger to happen, you can do it all in one step:

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
  Refresh.All
Sheets("sheetB").Select
  Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!RC:R[4]C)"
End Sub
```

You can then use an [On Open event](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm) to kick off the refresh and transpose macro and/or you can kick it off manually using the shortcut you specified* instead of hitting refresh

*I wouldn't recommend ctrl+p given that is the print hotkey

Comment: Hi Steph, thank you for the pointer regarding lack of VBA support for PowerQuery in Excel. But the solution you have suggested would also work fine for me. Ctrl + <any key> if it refreshes data as well as transposes data from query sheet to report sheet. SOunds perfect. Can I do a Refresh.All, then use Takedasama's answer above and then use a transpose macro after the check? Your help till now has been very useful. And I will change the key as suggested by you.

Answer (score 1):

This means you should have as many rows on Sheet(2) as Columns on Sheet (1). Thus your Trigger should Check if the Two are equal and if not run your transpose macro. Thus:

**Edit** I've added the `Worksheet_Change` to actually trigger the "interrogation" macro. This macro, if false, calls for the transpose macro. **Note!** Place the `Worksheet_Change` macro on `Sheet1` and the `Transpose Macro` anywhere you want. The search for last copy cell's row is rudimentary (but suffice for now). **Still** To transpose the cells you should really use the inverted `Cells(i,j).Copy` Than `Cells(j,i).Paste`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
LastRow = Sheets(2).Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
LastColumns = Sheets(1).Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1") 'Check on the header row only
    If Not Intersect(Target, SearchRange) Is Nothing Then
        If LastRow <> LastColumn Then Call YourTransposeMacro
    End If
End Sub

Sub YourTransposeMacro()
LastRowToCopy = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A1:A1000"))
'This method works only if you don't have blanks on your table (specially on column A)
LastColumn = Sheets(1).Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    For i = 1 To LastRowToCopy
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, LastColumn).Copy
        Sheets(2).Cells(LastColumn, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i
End Sub
```

The code above only covers the scenario where the new column is also placed as the last column (in sheet 1). Thow, as I see this, it would be much more simple to just copy all the data and transpose just after the the refresh *based on the Worksheet_Change).
**Any feedback is welcomed.**

Comment: ...and will need a change event statement included in the sheet's code as the trigger mechanism

Comment: Hello Takedasama, thank you for the inputs. They are a real pointer in the right direction. I had provided the transpose macro in the question. Can I just plug it in into your answer? Sorry if i sound like a noob, but the thing is I know about macros but have never used VBA before.

Comment: try it now. I've updated the answer.As for your Q: the transpose macro should be adjusted to the column you've just added and that cannot be *hard-coded* so you have to look for the last column. If a new column was added but is not the last one, the check is a bit more tricky. THe code above only covers the last column.

Comment: @StephLocke +1 I've amended the code to be triggered with `Worksheet_Change`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the [worksheet change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) should help.

Comment: Hi Yuvraj, thanks for your reply. WOuld this change event be the one Steph suggests we use with Takedasama's reply?

Comment: Yes, This is the way to do it. But this alone will not do anything. I've added the `Worksheet_Change` on the trigger macro.